# Break Field and Data in php

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I want to know how to break data from tag field become :

```
produk
test
murah
modem
```

It will break data inside a record when it has comma delimited

Thanks

Comment: The functions you are looking for are explode(',', $comma_string); and strpos($comma_sting, ','); but this is probably a duplicate question, you should do some more reasearch before posting here :)

Comment: I don't know what the keyword so i cannot find in stackoverflow.com and i think it's not a wrong way ask what i wanna know

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let you have fetched the data from the table then executing in the `while loop`. please ignore `mysql_*`, it might be `mysqli_*` also -

```
$tags = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_object($rec)) {
    $tags = array_merge($tags, explode(',', $res->tag)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php to query that columns,

then use PHP's [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method

from the docs examples:

```
$res  = "produk,test,murah,modem";
$res = explode(",", $res);
echo $res[0]; // produk
echo $res[1]; // test
```

Comment: That's not combining php and mysql query

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `explode()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

It would look something like this:

```
<?php
    //query goes here

   $values = explode(",",$row['tag']);
?>
```

Comment: I know about explode, what i want is combining php and mysqlquery